# How do I start a new Obj-C library project with Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ide, project

I am new to Xcode (and Objective C in general) and I want to create a new Objective-C Library (Framework?) which will be used by some of our iPhone applications in the future.

Which type of project should I choose when Xcode shows the new project dialog? I tried selecting "Blank Project" but then I faced some issues in defining the target, dependencies, etc.

I want my project to be easily re-usable in the future both in code form and as a `.dylib`.

I would appreciate some help with this. Links to online docs are welcome.

Comment: I wrote a little piece about this here http://www.memention.com/blog/2011/01/27/Frameworks-within.html But it's only for Mac as Apple has rules against it for iOS as Adrian writes.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3 of the SDK you are able to create library projects in Xcode. However, those projects do not create .dylib libraries, but static .a libraries.

You cannot create Frameworks for iOS, as Apple's own App Store rules state that apps sold through the App Store cannot load code dynamically, which is what Frameworks are for. Libraries are designed to be statically linked.